# A Gronwall type inequality involving iterated integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

Let $p(t), a(t)$ be non-negative, continuous functions on $[0,T]$. Suppose that we have:
$$p(t) \leq a(t) + C \int_0^t du e^{-\kappa(t-u)}p(u) \int_0^u ds e^{-\kappa(u-s)} p(s),$$
where $\kappa, C > 0$ are constants.

Can we derive a Gronwall type inequality for $p(t)$, under possibly additional assumptions on $p(t)$ and/or $a(t)$?